How to launch the Slint (Rust) application in maximized mode?
I am developing a desktop application in Rust using the Slint library and really want it to run in maximized mode. But I ran into a problem if I just use app.window().set_maximized(true); after that, launch the application, it will start in the maximized state and with the corresponding icon on the toolbar, but it will have the same dimensions with which it runs in windowed mode, and is located in the upper left corner.
Incorrectly maximized window
Meanwhile the app.run() function blocks the stream, which is why it does not work to assign the desired value to the parameter after the application is launched.
I tried using app.show().unwrap(); before get_maximized(), but it didn't affect the result in any way.
I also tried to expand the window in a separate thread, but Rust throws an error when trying to stream the slint application. As I understand it, this is due to the fact that GUI elements should be accessible only from the main stream.
Finally, I tried using chat gpt to solve this problem and it suggested using the Slint on_ready function, but I didn't find anything about this or a similar function in Slint. And the code proposed by chat gpt turned out to be completely non-working.

I don't have experience with Slint, but what I remember from messing with GUIs is that if you set a maximal window size, then it can't be made fullscreen. What you are describing sounds like this problem. Do you set max window dimenstions in your code, or in the Slint file?

@AleksanderKrauze, I set maximized in the rust code, after creating an instance of the window. The code looks like this:  fn main() {let app = AppWindow::new().unwrap(); app.window().set_maximized(true); app.run().unwrap(); }

So.. I spent some more time studying the slint rust api documentation and found the invoke_from_event_loop function.
As it turned out, my decision to create a separate thread was partially correct, all I had to do was wrap the set_maximized call in invoke_from_event_loop. The working code looks like this:
fn main() {
    let app = AppWindow::new().unwrap();
    let app_weak = app.as_weak();

    let thread = std::thread::spawn(move || {
        let app_copy = app_weak.clone();
        //Expand the slint window from event loop
        slint::invoke_from_event_loop(move || app_copy.unwrap().window().set_maximized(true)).unwrap();
        
        //Another code that we wanted to execute after the application was launched
        //For example: hide the console window peculiar to slint
    });

    thread.join().unwrap();
    app.run().unwrap();
}

Just as I understood from the documentation, the run() function first displays the window, and only after it starts the slint event loop, which means the code wrapped in invoke_from_event_loop will be executed only after the application is launched, which can be used as the on_ready function that I was looking for.

I found a clearer solution thanks to the original answer. We don't need threads, just scheduling the task in the event loop.
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let app = App::new()?;

    let weak_app = app.as_weak();
    slint::invoke_from_event_loop(move || weak_app.unwrap().window().set_maximized(true)).unwrap();

    app.run()?;

    Ok(())
}

